# Use SPFx to modify the 'edit form' from a modern document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Right now I am learning SPFx for SharePoint Online. My customer wants to modify the 'edit form' of a document library in a way that if a user starts typing keywords  into the Summary field, predifined keywords are displayed which share the same letters in the beginning. 
I was wondering if I can use SPFx to  geht this job done

[image]

I thought maybe I can bind the ID of the summary textbox to a javascript file which then does the heavy lifting. 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a edit form with SPFx, however, you can't replace the default edit form with the one you created with SPFx.

The only way to replace the default edit form is using PowerApps or InfoPath to create a new form, however, I don't think that we can achieve the goal with these two solution.

Maybe you should create your own list web part, and implement the edit button of the web part, such that the web part will show your edit form with the auto completion.